# How will you use the C# 4 dynamic type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0

C# 4 will contain a new `dynamic` keyword that will bring dynamic language features into C#.

How do you plan to use it in your own code, what pattern would you propose ? In which part of your current project will it make your code cleaner or simpler, or enable things you could simply not do (outside of the obvious interop with dynamic languages like IronRuby or IronPython)?

*PS : Please if you don't like this C# 4 addition, avoid to bloat comments negatively.*

Edit : refocussing the question.

The classic usages of dynamic are well known by most of stackoverflow C# users. What I want to know is if you think of specific new C# patterns where dynamic can be usefully leveraged without losing too much of C# spirit.

Comment: Duplicate question? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244302/what-do-you-think-of-the-new-c-4-0-dynamic-keyword

Comment: not really... the question is not 'do you like it ?' but what will you do with it. But it's true it's quite close. I made a search on a similar question but did not stumble on this one.

Comment: This is a discussion with no "right" answer. Therefore, it should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 13):

Wherever old-fashioned reflection is used now and code readability has been impaired. And, as you say, some Interop scenarios (I occasionally work with COM).

That's pretty much it. If `dynamic` usage can be avoided, it should be avoided. Compile time checking, performance, etc.

A few weeks ago, I remembered [this article](https://www.lucabol.com/posts/2009-02-05-simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0/). When I first read it, I was frankly appalled. But what I hadn't realised is that I didn't know how to even *use* an operator on some unknown type. I started wondering what the generated code would be for something like this:

```
dynamic c = 10;
int b = c * c;
```

Using regular reflection, you can't use defined operators. It generated quite a bit of code, using some stuff from a `Microsoft` namespace. Let's just say the above code is a lot easier to read :) It's nice that it works, but it was also *very* slow: about 10,000 times slower than a regular multiplication (doh), and about 100 times slower than an `ICalculator` interface with a Multiply method.

**Edit** - generated code, for those interested:

```
if (<Test>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Sitea == null)
  <Test>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Sitea =
    CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(
      new CSharpBinaryOperationBinder(ExpressionType.Multiply,
        false, false, new CSharpArgumentInfo[] {
          new CSharpArgumentInfo(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
          new CSharpArgumentInfo(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));
b = <Test>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site9.Target(
      <Test>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site9,
      <Test>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Sitea.Target(
        <Test>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Sitea, c, c));
```

Comment: I you think of cases where using reflection can be replaced by dynamic code, you can give a sample ?

Comment: @Think: It could be used in cases where functions are being reflectively invoked, not where reflection is being used to bypass accessibility (unless, I guess, you cast it to an object first? not sure...) or to do inspection.

Answer (score 7):

The dynamic keyword is all about simplifying the code required for two scenarios:

- C# to COM interop
- C# to dynamic language (JavaScript, etc.) interop

While it **could** be used outside of those scenarios, it probably **shouldn't** be.

Comment: have you got more information regarding your second point please scott? an C# managed game engine - exposing to an ajax graphics engine is something I am working on and would love to see how this would help!

Answer (score 5):

Recently I have blogged about dynamic types in C# 4.0 and among others I mentioned some of its potential uses as well as some of its pitfalls. The article itself is a bit too big to fit in here, but you can read it in full at this [address](http://www.ducons.com/blog/new-features-in-c-4-0#Dynamic_types).

As a summary, here are a few useful use cases (except the obvious one of interoping with COM libraries and dynamic languages like IronPython):

- reading a random XML or JSON into a dynamic C# object. The .Net framework contains classes and attributes for easily deserializing XML and JSON documents into C# objects, but only if their structure is static. If they are dynamic and you need to discover their fields at runtime, they can could only be deserialized into dynamic objects. .Net does not offer this functionality by default, but it can be done by 3rd party tools like [jsonfx](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx) or [DynamicJson](http://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/)
- return anonymous types from methods. Anonymous types have their scope constrained to the method where they are defined, but that can be overcome with the help of dynamic. Of course, this is a dangerous thing to do, since you will be exposing objects with a dynamic structure (with no compile time checking), but it might be useful in some cases. For example the following method reads only two columns from a DB table using Linq to SQL and returns the result:

  ```
  public static List<dynamic> GetEmployees()
  {
    List<Employee> source = GenerateEmployeeCollection();
    var queyResult = from employee in source
                  where employee.Age > 20
                  select new { employee.FirstName, employee.Age };

    return queyResult.ToList<dynamic>();
  }
  ```
- create REST WCF services that returns dynamic data. That might be useful in the following scenario. Consider that you have a web method that returns user related data. However, your service exposes quite a lot of info about users and it will not be efficient to just return all of them all of the time. It would be better if you would be able to allow consumers to specify the fields that they actually need, like with the following URL

  ```
  http://api.example.com/users?userId=xxxx&fields=firstName,lastName,age
  ```

  The problem then comes from the fact that WCF will only return to clients responses made out of serialized objects. If the objects are static then there would be no way to return dynamic responses so dynamic types need to be used. There is however one last problem in here and that is that by default dynamic types are not serializable. In the [article](http://www.ducons.com/blog/new-features-in-c-4-0#Dynamic_types) there is a code sample that shows how to overcome this (again, I am not posting it here because of its size).

In the end, you might notice that two of the use cases I mentioned require some workarounds or 3rd party tools. This makes me think that while the .Net team has added a very cool feature to the framework, they might have only added it with COM and dynamic languages interop in mind. That would be a shame because dynamic languages have some strong advantages and providing them on a platform that combines them with the strengths of strong typed languages would probably put .Net and C# ahead of the other development platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Miguel de Icaza presented a very cool use case on his blog, [here](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Aug-11.html) (source included):

```
dynamic d = new PInvoke ("libc");
d.printf ("I have been clicked %d times", times);
```

If it is possible to do this in a safe and reliable way, that would be awesome for native code interop.

Answer (score 3):

This will also allow us to avoid having to use the visitor pattern in certain cases as multi-dispatch will now be possible

```
public class MySpecialFunctions
{
  public void Execute(int x) {...}
  public void Execute(string x) {...}
  public void Execute(long x) {...}
}

dynamic x = getx();
var myFunc = new MySpecialFunctions();
myFunc.Execute(x);
```

...will call the best method match at runtime, instead of being worked out at compile time

Comment: Please help me understand the advantage here. Why would you not want this to be resolved at compile time?

Comment: Sometimes you don't know what type you are working with - for example you're working with a baseclass but need special behaviour for subtypes.
When transversing a tree structure, each node might inherit off a base class node, but when processing the node you need specific behaviour for subtypes (ie. composite node). You can utilize a class like MySpecialFunctions and call Execute without huge switch/if blocks trying to work out which method to call by checking the type of the node being proccessed. The client code doesn't have to be aware of all subtypes to utilize MySpecialFunctions correctly

Comment: Also new/alternate subtypes of MySpecialFunctions would not require changes to client code proccessing nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I will use it to simplify my code which deals with COM/Interop where before I had to specify the member to invoke, its parameters etc. (basically where the compiler didn't know about the existence of a function and I needed to describe it at compile time). With dynamic this gets less cumbersome and the code gets leaner.

Comment: Excelent blog entry and code that will simplify Interop a lot can be found here: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Aug-11.html