# C# Practical usage of the dynamic keyword

Tags: c#, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How will you use the C# 4 dynamic type ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293984/how-will-you-use-the-c-4-dynamic-type)

What would be actual practical usages of the dynamic keyword?

```
dynamic a = 1;
a.Crash();
```

I know the case where it is more readable in XML chains, but, other than that, what is it good for?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a good article:

> As a developer, you use the dynamic
>   keyword with variables expected to
>   contain objects of uncertain type such
>   as objects returned from a COM or DOM
>   API; obtained from a dynamic language
>   (IronRuby, for example); from
>   reflection; from objects built
>   dynamically in C# 4.0 using the new
>   expand capabilities.

[Using the Dynamic Keyword in C# 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336309.aspx)

Comment: +1. Nice article. Specially regarding `var vs. dynamic` because many people think they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's particularly useful in COM interop scenarios, where you normally have to write a lot of interop plumbing code.

Comment: DIAF DTE[.](http://derp)

Answer (score 1):

The most practical use i've found is dealing with COM interop scenarios.  Many legacy COM components end up generating signatures that are unusable from managed code without a great deal of casting due to many items getting marshaled as `object`.  It leads to code like the following.

```
IUser GetAUser() { ... }
IUser user = GetAUser();
IAddress address = (IAddress)user.GetAddress();
int zipCode = (int)address.GetZipCode();
```

This gets even worse with deeply nested hierarchies.  While this code is type safe in the sense that it doesn't violate any CLR rules it's unsafe in the sense that the developer is depending on implementation details of the types in order to get the work done.  It's really no safer than the dynamic equivalent.

```
dynamic GetAUser() { ... }
int zipCode = (int)GetAUser().GetAddress().GetZipCode();
```

Comment: Doesn't the dynamic version of the example code violate the 'two dots' prohibition for writing COM-interop code (i.e. the code generated 'hidden' RCWs)?

Answer (score 0):

The DLR(Dynamic Language Runtime) basically enables everyone to talk to everyone. That includes not just Python and Ruby, but Silverlight, Office/COM, and others.

Comment: also this is a good read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned it is very useful in COM interop scenarios.

Also, it is very useful on [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3). You can have views with dynamic a model. You also have `ViewBag` object that can hold anything.

And another use is to hold a [`json` object, if you implement a `DynamicObject` class](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx). This is **very** useful when consuming APIs.

Comment: I've been quite disappointed with the use of dynamic in MVC view models.  It's pretty much hamstrung.  You can't pass dynamic to extension methods which means you need to cast it to a known type for use in HTMLHelper methods,  and you can't pass anonymous types into a dynamic view as they are compiled as internal.  It's one of those things that sounds good - but in practice isn't.

Comment: @James tested an anonymous object and that really doesn't work. I've remembered another use for dynamic and added that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dynamic keyword with POCOs can be extremely useful when you have several method overloads and you've received the the argument as an object. Cast the argument to dynamic and it will resolve the correct overload based on runtime type-- doing without dynamic ends up being a series of if/elseif statements, yuck.

Using the dynamic keyword with DynamicObjects subclasses allows you to get rid of boiler plate, write fluent api's more easily and create code that is by far more malleable. For example, here is a dynamic api that get rid of a ton of boilerplate code related to MVVM binding http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageMVVM